# Get max value from JSON objects D3JS

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a JSON file like this :

```
{  
   "directed":false,
   "graph":[  
      [  
         "node_default",
         {  

         }
      ],
      [  
         "name",
         "()_with_int_labels"
      ],
      [  
         "edge_default",
         {  

         }
      ]
   ],
   "nodes":[  
      {  
         "id":0,
         "Year":1996,
         "Venue":"SWAT",
         "cYear":1996,
         "label":"The randomized complexity of maintaining the minimum"
      },
      {  
         "id":1,
         "Year":1998,
         "Venue":"SWAT",
         "cYear":1998,
         "label":"Probabilistic data structures for priority queues"
      }
   ],
   "links":[  
      {  
         "Edge Id":"12640",
         "target":65,
         "source":0,
         "Year":2011
      },
      {  
         "Edge Id":"12714",
         "target":50,
         "source":0,
         "Year":1996
      }
   ],
   "multigraph":false
}
```

I'd like to get the maximum value of the variable `Year`  from the `nodes` and show it in the console log at first and then use it as variable for further processing.

What I did was this :

```
d3.json("swatwads.json", function(error, graph) {
  graphdata=graph;
  graphRec=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph)); //Add this line

  // Node and Link habitual defitions

  console.log(d3.max(d3.values(graph.nodes, function(d) {return d.Year;} )));

  });
```

When I run the code it retrieves the entire first `nodes` object  while what I want is the maximum value the variable `Year` of the `nodes` objects.

What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you stringify your object `graph` then turn the string back into an object using parse? This seems unnecessary.  If it's an object already why turn it to json to just turn it back to an obj??? `graphRec=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph));` Or are you trying to break the reference?

Comment: `graphdata ==graph == graphRec` all 3 of these objects seem pointless. Just use graph!!

Comment: @Liam seems legit, I saw an example which says it is a good practice when it comes to retrieving data but not in my case. I removed that line but I still get the same results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply want the line

```
console.log(d3.max(graph.nodes, function(d) {return d.Year;} ));
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utyj40uq/1/)

So you just want the `max` value of `year` from `graph.nodes`

Full example

```
d3.json("swatwads.json", function(error, graph) {
  console.log(d3.max(graph.nodes, function(d) {return d.Year;} ));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
d3.json("swatwads.json", function(error, graph) {
  var nodes = graph.nodes
  var max = 0
  for (var ii=0, node; node=nodes[ii]; ii++){
    if (node.Year > max) {
      max = node.Year
    }
  }
  console.log(max)
}
```

Comment: This kinda defeats the object of using d3 if your just going to do it yourself?